# Why is this function's return value ignored?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm fairly sure the problem here is simply I'm not thinking in the necessary, asynchronous way yet for Node.js.

I have a function `userExists()` in a module `db` which checks whether a user is in a database when passed an email, and returns `true` or `false`.

The relevant part:

```
userExists : function(email) {
    var client = new pg.Client(app.conString);
    var query;
    var result = false;

    client.connect();

    query = client.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1",
        [email]
    );

    query.on('row', function(row) {
        result = true;
    });

    query.on('end', function() {
        client.end();
        return result;
    });
```

I am calling it like this:

```
if (!db.userExists(req.session.email)) {
        newUser();
    } else {
        updateUser();
    }
}
```

It is always `newUser()` which is called, whatever `userExists()` returns. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the time wrong. The queries finishes after you function is run, so you need to pass a callback function and "wait" for the result.

```
userExists = function(email, cb) {
    var client = new pg.Client(app.conString);
    var query;
    var result = false;

    client.connect();

    query = client.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1",
        [email]
    );

    query.on('row', function(row) {
        result = true;
    });

    query.on('end', function() {
        client.end();
        cb(result);
    });
}


// Time 1: ask is the user exists
db.userExists(req.session.email, function(exists) {
    // Time 3: Yeah result came back
    if (exists) {
        updateUser()
    }
    else {
        newUser();
    }
});
// Time 2: I've asked, let's wait for the result
// The following code will likely be executed before you get the result back
```

Comment: Thanks! I was basically there but for some reason couldn't make the final leap. I blame it on my flu.

Comment: No biggie. It takes awhile to adjust to nodes async flow.